# How To Create A New User Using The ParseReact Framework

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, reactjs

I am learning the new ParseReact framework and I want to know how to create a User object.

This is what I have:

```js
ParseReact.Mutation.Create('User', {
  username: 'johndoe',
  password: 'test',
  email: 'john@doe.com',
  emailVerified: 'false'
}).dispatch();
```

I get a **"POST https://api.parse.com/1/classes/User 400 (Bad Request)"** error message

Reference: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseReact/blob/master/docs/DataMutations.md

Answer (score 0):

Use '_User' not 'User'.

```
  ParseReact.Mutation.Create('_User', {
    username: 'johndoe',
    password: 'test',
    email: 'john@doe.com',
    emailVerified: 'false'
  }).dispatch()
  .then(() => {
    console.log('ok');
  })
  .fail((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```